# php 5.3.x [PATH=<path>] and [HOST=<host>] configuration directive

Tags: php

Can anyone explain how i can use theses directives?
I found official documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sections.php#ini.per-path). But not much explained.

Here is problem. Server A is running cpanel, php 5.3.10

php.ini contains this:

```
suhosin.executor.disable_eval=On
[PATH=/home/username/public_html]
suhosin.executor.disable_eval=Off
```

I have file under: `/home/username/public_html/afd/evaltest.php` and eval is working. If i comment path section, php shows error, that eval is disabled. So, all is working as expected.

Server B is the same, but php version is `5.3.19` and application is `codeigniter` and that does not working. If i add to php.ini

```
[HOST=www.example.com]
suhosin.executor.disable_eval=Off

[HOST=example.com]
suhosin.executor.disable_eval=Off
```

then all works like expected. So, why path does not work on server B ?

Can i add multiple path to directive? like this

```
[PATH=/home/username/public_html, /home/username2/public_html, /home/usernameN/public_html]
suhosin.executor.disable_eval=Off
```

or

```
[PATH=/home/username/public_html]
[PATH=/home/username2/public_html
[PATH=/home/usernameN/public_html
suhosin.executor.disable_eval=Off
```

on both serves php is running as suPHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why on server B `[PATH=]` does not work. On server A later we added storage and mounted it to `/home_new`, after that when moved account from server A (witch is located on `/home_new`) to B, on server B was created `/home_new` directory and new user was created under `/home_new`. Then created symbolic links from `/home_new/username` folder to `/home/username`. And `[PATH=]` does not work with symbolic links.
I tried with `[PATH=/home/username/public_html]` witch is symbolic link,but i must use `[PATH=/home_new/username/public_html]` and then all work like expected.

P.S. sorry for not so good English.